# Angularjs ng-checked post php request not set true value

Tags: php, angularjs

I am creating a survey questions, for creating question i have a php class, based on question type that class return questions and options. i am facing dificulties with checkbox.

my class function for creation checkbox following:

```
protected function QuestionTypeCheckbox(){
            $CheckBoxAnswer=$this->getAnswerByQuestionId();
            $rowscheckbox=$this->getOptions();
            if($rowscheckbox==TRUE){
            $optioncheckbox=NULL;     
               foreach ($rowscheckbox as $row) {
                   if(in_array($row->option_order, (explode(',', $CheckBoxAnswer)))) 
                    {
                     $selected= true;
                     //$check = 'checked';
                     } else{
                         $selected=0;
                     //$check = '';
                     }
                    $optioncheckbox= $optioncheckbox.
                        "<label class='checkbox-inline'><input type='checkbox' ng-checked='$selected' ng-true-value='$row->option_order' ng-model='question_$this->Qid".".Value$row->option_order' name=".""."question_$this->Qid[]".""." value='$row->option_order'>$row->option</label>";
              }
              return $optioncheckbox;
              }
              else {return "FALSE";}

        }
```

when i am getting the checkbox lookline following:

```
<div class="form-group">
<label >3.Water supply<br></label><br><label class='checkbox-inline'>
<input type='checkbox' ng-checked='1' ng-true-value='1' ng-model='question_4.Value1' name=question_4[] value='1'>TubeWell</label>
<label class='checkbox-inline'><input type='checkbox' ng-checked='0' ng-true-value='2' ng-model='question_4.Value2' name=question_4[] value='2'>Pond</label>
<label class='checkbox-inline'><input type='checkbox' ng-checked='0' ng-true-value='3' ng-model='question_4.Value3' name=question_4[] value='3'>River</label>
<label class='checkbox-inline'><input type='checkbox' ng-checked='1' ng-true-value='4' ng-model='question_4.Value4' name=question_4[] value='4'>Canel</label>                    </div>
    </div>
```

when returning the checkbox then its working fine. its showing the value with checked value.
But problem is when i submit the form then its returning null value. but if i deselect and select again selected checkbox then its return value.

```
<form ng-submit="InsertData(question_4)">
```

Comment: it could be because of `value` attribute, you don't need to use `value` just use `ng-true-val` for checked value and  `ng-false-value` for unchecked and if you don't want unchecked value then don't add `ng-false-value`

Comment: its not working, dont know why its not passing any value